# How to print only results different from zero?

Tags: bash

I've this script. I would like to print only the non-zero results.
My enviroment is Os X

`find /PATH/ -type f -exec basename "{}" | grep -i "Word" | wc -l`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you count selected records, you do not have to filter on 0 hits.
This command shows all basenames that appear once or more.

```
find . -type f -iname '*Word*' -printf "%f\n" | sort | uniq -c
```

You might want to add `| sort -n` on the and to see which file occurs most.

Maybe you wanted something: How often `Word` occurs in different files.

```
grep -Rci while  | grep -v ":0$"
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you assume OP wants to find duplicate filenames in general, rather than how many files match `*Word*`. They also wanted output when the answer was just 1, which is not a duplicate.

Comment: @joanis Without the `basename` every line would occur exactly once, and using `wc` would only show haw much filenames have `Word` in it. (S)he tried to improve it with `basename`, and I was wondering why. And counting? It could be looking for duplicates, or for files uoloaded often or some other statistics. Only explanation of the use of `basename` I could think of, is trying to count distinct filenames.

Answer (score 2):

First, here is a much faster find command that will do the same thing:

```
find /PATH/ -type f -iname '*Word*' | wc -l
```

Now, you can put this optimized command into an if statement:

```
if [[ `find /PATH/ -type f -iname '*Word*' | wc -l` ]]; then
   find /PATH/ -type f -iname '*Word*' | wc -l
fi
```

To run the command just once, save the result into a variable:

```
count=`find /PATH/ -type f -iname '*Word*' | wc -l`
if [[ $count -gt 0 ]]; then
   echo $count
fi
```

Comment: I think OP uses basename for finding duplicate filenames (in different folders).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep -v` to remove output that consists of just zero (with spaces before it, 'cause that's what `wc` prints). With @joanis' optimization of the search, that gives:

```
find /PATH/ -type f -iname '*Word*' | wc -l | grep -v '^ *0$'
```

Comment: I think OP uses basename for finding duplicate filenames (in different folders).